# SQLAlchemy: how to retrieve count of an ORM Select query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following query in SQLAlchemy 2 ORM. Most documentation I found is related to version 1 and I can't find how to efficiently get the count of these queries.

```py
messages = select(VoicemailMessage).where(VoicemailMessage.voicemail_box_id == self.box.id)
unplayed_messages = messages.where(VoicemailMessage.is_played == False)
played_messages = messages.where(VoicemailMessage.is_played == True)
```

So how can I get the count of these objects? Later in the code, depending on some conditions, I need to loop through the actual messages.

I was hoping to be able to do something like:

```
if unplayed_messages.count() > 0:
   speak("These are your messages")

   for m in self.x.db.scalars(unplayed_messages):
       self.play_message(m)
```

But count() is not recognized.